# expressjs and module exports for routes with index

Tags: node.js, express, module, routes

I'm trying to wrap my brain around using an index.js file to export my routes in an express-app.

**./app.js**

```
const server = require('express'),
      app    = server(),
      port   = process.env.PORT

require('./routes/index')(app)
app.listen(port)
```

**./routes/index.js**

```
function routes(app) {
    require('./test')(app)
}
module.exports = routes
```

**./routes/test.js**

```
function test(app) {
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        console.info('test')
        res.end('Hello, World!')
    })
}

module.exports = test
```

Now, of course, when I execute ./app.js I get an error telling me that `require( ... ) is not a function on ./routes/index.js:2`

But I really can't seem to wrap my brain around this logic. Not the reason for my error, but how to bind modules together in this structure, while passing `app` to the modules.

The idea behind this structure (in case that's not obvious) is to create a system, where modules can be added and removed from the app by adding and removing them from the index file that belongs to each module, and then only require the index for each module-cluster (for example routes).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason exporting named functions like

```
function someName(parameter) {
    require('./whatever')(parameter)
}
module.exports = someName
```

wont work...

However, exporting anonymous functions do work:

```
module.exports = function (parameter) {
    require('./whatever')(parameter)
}
```

Comment: That's really odd, cause it doesn't work on my end. Node -v 4.2.4

Comment: The literal code that you posted in your question works fine in that specific version of Node. Is this really all the code?

Comment: some minor differences that (AFAIK) should not affect the issue, but maybe you can tell me? `port` is set to process.env.PORT || 1337, and I am configuring app to use body-parser. I also made a static route: `app.use(server.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 }))`

Comment: That wouldn't case the issue you're running into, no.